# I am unable to sort single column dataset

Tags: excel, vb.net, sorting

I received the following error when I try to `Sort` the content of a single column (A1:A2010) of data for a Worksheet

```
Run-time Error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

```vb
Scripting:
Dim BoldUsers As Worksheet 
Set BoldUsers = Worksheets("50boldUusersdata")
Set BoldUsersRange = Sheets("50boldusersdata").Range("A1:A2010")

SortBoldUsers

Sub SortBoldUsers()
Sheet6.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Sheet6.Range("A1:A2010").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=x1Yes
End Sub
```

> Additional Information:
> •   The worksheet was copied from another Workbook and all of the other non-relevant columns were >deleted leaving the column that needs sorting. (Not sure if the fact that the worksheet was copied from another Workbook is contributing to the sort failure)
> •   Within the script (not shown), I was able to successfully sort a similar one column worksheet without issue.

I have tried numerous things to resolve the issue but my VB acumen is challenged. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a typo: "50bold**Uu**sersdata"

Comment: Which line returns the error?

Comment: @ZygD Wouldn't that result in a `Subscript out of Range` error?

Comment: Doesn't look like vb.net. Is this code written in Visual Studio?

Comment: @ZygD Yes, I made the typo when I .edited my comment.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfield The error is raised when the "Sheet6.Range("A1:A2010").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=x1Yes" is executed

Comment: @Keno176 - you should edit your question to fix the typo

Comment: In your case I would suggest changing the sheet's code name to something more specific than Sheet6. Maybe some  other open (or not properly closed) workbook having Sheet6 impedes the execution of this script.

Comment: Try:  `Key1:=Sheet6.Range("A1")`  The way you have it written in your code, it will pick `A1` on whatever the active sheet is at the time.  If the active sheet is not `Sheet6`, you'll get a 1004 error (albeit with a different description than what you show).

Comment: @Ron Rosenfield - I made the change as per recommendation - same error raised.

Comment: @ZygD - I made the change as per recommendation - same error raised

Comment: To me the code would not even run if I used `Header:=x1Yes`. I had to use `Header:=1`. But this is probably not what causes your error. I think you need to provide more details/ fuller code that you use. Seems that we explored everything what we can think of from what is provided.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Probably something in your data or in code you have not shared. Perhaps reading HELP for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might provide some clues as to how to better present the problem so we can reproduce it and solve it for you.